# How can I transform this div to bottom and add some random pop-up squares

Tags: jquery, css

I dont, know how to transform this div to bottom. And I have no idea how can I spawn for a moment pop-up squares (simple divs) in random directions that will disappear after 50ms.

I tried to float this box to bottom but it didn't help.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
});
```

```css
.field {
  height: 340px;
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #218D9B;
  height: 320px;
  width: 160px;
  float: bottom;
  background-image: url("img/tree.png");
  background-size: 100%;
}

.transform {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.transform-active {
  height: 0px;
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <div class="box transform"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
```

I expect the effect of wood hiding in the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to transform the div height to the bottom, you can use positioning.
Add `position: relative` to the parent, then you can edit the box element using `position: absolute` and `bottom: 20px`.

```
.field {
    height: 340px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.box {
    background-color: #218D9B;
    height: 320px;
    background-image: url(img/tree.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Another solution, depending on the situation, would be to use `transform: scale()` instead of `height` for animation.
You can scale only vertically and set `transform-origin: bottom`.

```
.box {
    background-color: #218D9B;
    height: 320px;
    width: 160px;
    background-image: url(img/tree.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
.transform-active {
    transform: scale(1, 0);
    width: 160px;
}
```